# Call NotifyPropertyChanged from different ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have a Canvas setup inside an ItemsControl, which I am populating with buttons. Each button has an X and Y position property which is used to position the button on the canvas.

What im trying to do is make the item positions relative to the size of the canvas. My problem is when I resize the canvas, the button ViewModels are not getting the NotifyPropertyChanged call, so their positions never update.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding PosY, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding PosX, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ToggleButton}">
            <local:ToggleButton DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

in the ToggleButtonViewModel:

```
    public double PosY {
        get {
            return (_Button.PositionVertical * Size[1]);
        }
    }

    public double PosX {
        get { return (_Button.PositionHorizontal * Size[0]); }
    }
```

Size is a double[] with the X and Y dimensions of the canvas. I've tried storing it in the CanvasViewModel, in which case I can keep it updated with a SizeChanged event on the canvas, but then I couldnt figure out how to update the PosX and PosY in the ToggleButtonViewModel when the size changes.
I also tried storing the size as a static parameter in all of the ToggleButtonViewModels, but i couldnt use a NotifyPropertyChanged with a static parameter.

Any ideas how I could get the PosX and PosY to update when the size of the canvas changes?

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}" is yur datacontext inside your item control. So DataContext="{Binding}" is useless. If you want to use PosY or PosX, you have set correctly your data context during the binding

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is pointless. Even if the Top or Left properties were to be changed by the UI, a TwoWay Binding to a readonly property makes no sense at all. And `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has absolutely nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Instead of trying to update PosX and PosY whenever the Canvas size changes, it would make sense to create a [custom Canvas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-panel-element) that handles Left and Top (or its own set of attached properties) as relative values in the range 0..1. Just derive from Canvas (or Panel) and override ArrangeOverride.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go here, would be to implement a custom Panel which overrides your Arrange Logic, just like Clemens suggested, and add some attached Properties for the Positioning.
I made a really quick small solution for it and it seems to work like you want it to.

Its a simple Panel "*RelativePositionCanvas*", that supplies two attached Properties "*RelativeX*" and "*RelativeY*" which are double values which usually range from 0 to 1, and are used for setting the position of the top left corner, relative to the panel's size.

If you want to add more like aligning it to the right side, or making the size relative, you would just have to add some additional Attached Properties for those and use them in the ArrangeOverride method.

```
public class RelativePositionCanvas : Panel
{
    #region Properties
    #region RelativeX
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RelativeXProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "RelativeX",
                typeof(double),
                typeof(RelativePositionCanvas),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                        0.0d, 
                        new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPositioningChanged)));

    public static double GetRelativeX(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (double)d.GetValue(RelativeXProperty);
    }
    public static void SetRelativeX(DependencyObject d, double value)
    {
        d.SetValue(RelativeXProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion

    #region RelativeY
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RelativeYProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "RelativeY",
                typeof(double),
                typeof(RelativePositionCanvas),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                        0.0d,
                        new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPositioningChanged)));
    public static double GetRelativeY(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (double)d.GetValue(RelativeYProperty);
    }
    public static void SetRelativeY(DependencyObject d, double value)
    {
        d.SetValue(RelativeYProperty, value);
    }
    #endregion

    private static void OnPositioningChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement uie = d as UIElement;
        if (uie != null)
        {
            RelativePositionCanvas p = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(uie) as RelativePositionCanvas;
            if (p != null)
                p.InvalidateArrange();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Size childConstraint = new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity);

        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            if (child == null) { continue; }
            child.Measure(childConstraint);
        }

        return new Size();
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        var children = this.Children;
        foreach(UIElement child in children)
        {
            if (child == null) { continue; }

            var childRelativeX = GetRelativeX(child);
            var childRelativeY = GetRelativeY(child);

            var posX = childRelativeX * arrangeSize.Width;
            var posY = childRelativeY * arrangeSize.Height;
            child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(posX, posY), child.DesiredSize));
        }
        return arrangeSize;
    }
}
```

To use it you would have to replace the ItemsPanelTemplate by the RelativePositionCanvas, and the *Canvas.Top*, and *Canvas.Left* properties by the *RelativePositionCanvas.RelativeY* and *RelativePositionCanvas.RelativeX* properties and should be fine to go

Comment: `if (child == null) { continue; }` is pointless. You also don't need a PropertyChangedCallback for the RelativeX/Y properties that calls InvalidateArrange. Just register them with `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange`

Comment: Thats not right.. The AffectsArrange on the Properties would just trigger a rearrange on the Child, as the Property is just attached to it, but not in the Parent container, which would be the one responsible for arranging the button inside the panel (The RelativePositionCanvas itself), so nothing would happen until something else triggers a rearrange. And the Children collection could contain entries which are not UIElements, thats would you would also find this safety check in every .net panel's source code.

Comment: Then use `AffectsParentArrange`. Children or InternalChildren won't contain anything that is not a UIElement. Their type is `UIElementCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

Option1) In the ToggleButtonViewModel, change your definitions of PosX and PosY to be "normal" WPF notifying properties (I assume you know what I mean) which notify when changed. When the values in Size change, set the properties on your ViewModel. For example:

```
_viewModel.PosY = _Button.PositionVertical * Size[1];
_viewModel.PosX = _Button.PositionHorizontal * Size[0];
```

This gives a nice separation of concerns; but may not be possible, depending on where you are holding what information.

Option2) Add a method to your ViewModel which you can call to indicate that Size has changed, within which you can:

```
RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(PosX));
RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(PosY));
```

(I can give you an implementation of RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged if you need, but it's pretty standard WPF boilerplate code that you're likely to already have in your ViewModel.)